# Bug in chrome app with notification slider, starts search on page

Tags: chrome-for-android, bugs, search, oneplus

So I have this bug, I already reported it to OnePlus but didn't get any feedback.

I have a OnePlus 8T, which has a physical notification slider above the lock button on the side of the phone. This slider will put the phone in silent, vibrate, or sound-on mode. The bug is that whenever I do this when I'm in the google chrome app, it will start a search on page.

Is this a bug that people know about? Is it a feature? Any ideas what it could be?

I provided a screenshot below to show what I mean. Sorry for the dutch, but as you can see it started a "search on page" when on the right you see that it also switched to vibration mode

[image: Sorry for the dutch, but as you can see it started a "search on page" when on the right you see that it also switched to vibration mode]

Comment: This appears that Chrome tries to overlay a Search operation via a hardware operation, and then pass the control to the hardware layer for its proper operation, too. Search the Chrome options for shortcuts, gestures, something like that, to switch it off if possible.

Comment: According to [the Oneplus community post](https://community.oneplus.com/thread/1155070), looks like it's possible to customize the alert slider: "*There’s also ways to customize it teeny bit as well. From the settings menu go to (Buttons & Gestures) then tap on (Alert slider) You can adjust each of the 3 triggers there are a few options you can toggle on and off. One thing that persists however through all 3 settings is the alarm.*" Could you try checking it?